# Where to find the html.tpl.php $head variable content generation

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a way to edit the $head variable of the html.tpl.php.
Where exactly is this variable composed and set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to add information to the `<head>` is using  [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7).

If the data you want to alter was added using that function, you can alter it by implementing [`hook_html_head_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) within a custom module. Using the alter hook requires that you know the `$key` of the data that was added during `drupal_add_html_head()`.

If you want to alter CSS or JS, use [`hook_css_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) and [`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) respectively.